# How to FILTER Cassandra TimeUUID/UUID in Pig

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig, datastax-enterprise

Here is my Cassandra schema, using [Datastax Enterprise](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/)

```
CREATE KEYSPACE applications
  WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1};

USE applications;

CREATE TABLE events(
  bucket text, 
  id timeuuid,
  app_id uuid,  
  event text, 
  PRIMARY KEY(bucket, id)
);
```

I want to **FILTER** in PIG by `app_id` (TimeUUID) and `id` (UUID), here is my Pig script.

```
events = LOAD 'cql://applications/events'
  USING CqlStorage()
  AS (bucket: chararray, id: chararray, app_id: chararray, event: chararray);

result = FOREACH events GENERATE bucket, id, app_id;
DESCRIBE result;
DUMP result;
```

Here is the result

```
result: {bucket: chararray,id: chararray,app_id: chararray}
(2014-02-28-04,?O]??4??p??M?,;??F? (|?Mb) \n
(2014-02-28-04,?O??4??p??M?,?h^@?E????)
(2014-02-28-04,?V???4??p??M?,;??F? (|?Mb)
(2014-02-28-04,?W?0?4??p??M?,?h^@?E????)
(2014-02-28-04,?X^p?4??p??M?,?h^@?E????)
```

Notice, the `app_id`, and `id` fields are binary and I need to filter by some UUID, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use a UDF to convert the binary bytes of UUID/TimeUUID to chararray. Don't try to define it as chararray directly like AS (bucket: chararray, id: chararray, app_id: chararray, event: chararray);

Or you can use https://github.com/cevaris/pig-dse/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dse/pig/udfs/AbstractCassandraStorage.java which convert UUID/TimeUUID to String

File a Cassandra ticket if you think it's good to convert UUID to string as default.

Comment: Yup, you are right. The next issue I ran into is how trying to store the converted String UUID/TimeUUID back into a UUID/TimeUUID type. Since I was using CQL3 in Cassandra, there was a type check and it did not like the chararray version of the UUID/TimeUUID. I assume I would have to parse every chararray to see if it is a UUID/TimeUUID and convert it back before storing. I just ditched the UUID comparisons all together in Pig, and moved on.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve using a custom version of CQLStorage UDF Pig Loader. The issue was that Cassandras CQLStorage/CassandraStorage Pig loaders do not know how to handle UUID/TimeUUID types. I assume this happens for most non-standard data types. Anyways, here is the link to the coded solution on github.

https://github.com/cevaris/pig-dse