# Filter by UUID in Pig

Tags: filter, apache-pig, uuid, literals

I have a list of known UUIDs. I want to do a FILTER in Pig that filters out records whose id column do not contain a UUID from my list.

I have yet to find a way to specify bytearray literals such that I can write that filter statement.

How do I filter by UUID?

(in one attempt I tried using https://github.com/cevaris/pig-dse per [How to FILTER Cassandra TimeUUID/UUID in Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159722/how-to-filter-cassandra-timeuuid-uuid-in-pig) thinking I could filter by a chararray literal of the UUID but I got

```
grunt> post_creators= LOAD 'cql://mykeyspace/mycf/' using AbstractCassandraStorage;
2014-10-09 14:56:05,597 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: could not instantiate 'AbstractCassandraStorage' with arguments 'null'
```

)

Comment: Let me understand: u have two lists - one with known UUIDs, and another with IDs. You want to select IDs that are not on UUIDs list. Right?

Comment: Not quite. Let's say I have a UUID as an argument to a pig script, (let's say it's a User's UUID). I want to filter a table in storage by this UUID. (We could expand that to be a list of UUIDs as an argument, but the same principle applies.) What I can't figure out is how to specify a UUID in a FILTER command.

Comment: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/basic.html#filter

Comment: And if you want to use script parameter use: pig -f script.pig -param UUID=UUIDvalue and in filter just use: X = FILTER A BY UserId == '$UUID';

Comment: How do I specify a UUID specifically in Pig? The string representation of my UUID is 'dd2e03a7-7d3d-45b9-b902-2b39c5c541b5', but if I write this line of Pig code, it will not find my UUID because Pig only sees my UUID in terms of bytes.

Comment: posters = FILTER posters by poster_id == 'dd2e03a7-7d3d-45b9-b902-2b39c5c541b5';

Comment: Could you give an example of filtering by a specific, actual UUID?

Answer (score 0):

Use this python UDF

```
import array
import uuid
@outputSchema("uuid:bytearray")
def to_bytes(uuid_str):
    return array.array('b', uuid.UUID(uuid_str).bytes)
```

Filter like this:

```
users = FILTER users by user_id == my_udf.to_bytes('dd2e03a7-7d3d-45b9-b902-2b39c5c541b5');
```